# Synonym for meanwhile

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to write an academic essay. But I am stuck in connecting two sentences.
I want to find a substitute for the **meanwhile** connector because I have already overused it in the other parts of my essay. Could you please kindly let me know an academic-friendly suitable synonym or another connector.

> In recent years, most optimization research is dedicated to solving problems in the domains of business, construction, and supply chain management. **Meanwhile**, Simplex, Lagrange, and NewX are probably the most commonly studied methods in empirical works.

I have already checked online but I couldn't find much information googling. Really appreciate your help

Comment: Why not just drop _meanwhile_ since you're talking about the current situation?

Comment: I'm not sure you're using *meanwhile* correctly. See [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=synonym+meanwhile) for synonyms, none of which fit your sentence.

Comment: I don't think *meanwhile* fits here.  *Simplex, Lagrange, and NewX* are the subject of the first sentence, not merely OR techniques that are happening at the same time (= *meanwhile*)

Comment: Having no knowledge of optimisation techniques, it's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you contrasting the use in empirical works with those in business/construction/etc, or saying they're the same thing?

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/meanwhile

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure '*meanwhile*' is the right word to use for looking for synonyms. I think it is used idiomatically more than literally here.
'*Meanwhile*' means '*at the same time*', but also '*concurrently*', '*simultaneously*', i.e. happening at the same time.
What I think your wording wants to express is something like '*on the other hand*', '*however*', '*nevertheless*', i.e. a (seeming) contradiction. Perhaps those synonyms are helpful.